# Big Sur switched to zsh terminal but still uses .bash_profile

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, big-sur, zsh

I've upgraded to Big Sur and noticed my user was still using bash shell, so I changed *Users → Advanced Options → Login* shell to `/bin/zsh` and restarted.

The shell that starts appears to be zsh insofar this happens:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

But the terminal never sources `~/.zshrc`, it actually is still sourcing `~/.bash_profile` and I don't understand why. New sessions also still gives this warning:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

I've already run `chsh` but it doesn't have anything to change, and it definitely points to `/bin/zsh`. If I create a new user it uses zsh and `~/.zshrc` as expected.

I'm starting to suspect that my default shell is in fact **not** zsh, but is actually still using bash.. Can anyone tell me what's wrong that causes my terminal to not behave like a new user's, or how I can further debug this issue?

EDIT: Yeah it's stuck on bash:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
  892 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
  869 ttys001    0:00.01 -bash
 1011 ttys002    0:00.01 -bash
```

How can that be? My user settings definitely point to zsh:
[image: user advanced options with highlighted login shell pointing to /bin/zsh]

Comment: Have you tried restarting your machine after setting zsh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using macOS's Terminal.app? It might be overriding this in its Preferences:

[image]